# Wait until promise returned

Tags: javascript, html, promise

I found some code here on Stackoverflow to load files from your local disk. Everything worked fine in one big function. Now I tried to break the code apart in smaller functions.

I want to load all the img.src on the DOM in an array and add the files that the user selected to the array. And than do something with the Array.

I created:

```js
document.getElementById('picField').onchange = function (evt) {
    loadImg(evt);
}

async function loadImg(evt) {
    let imgInDom = await getImgFromDom();
    let allFiles = await loadAllFiles(imgInDom, evt);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(allFiles))
    //doSometing(allFiles);
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(allFiles))
    }, 2000);

}

function getImgFromDom() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('loadedImg');
        let source = [];

        for (x = 0; x < elements.length; x++) {
            source.push(elements[x].src)
        }

        resolve(source);
    });
}

function loadAllFiles(imgFromDom, evt) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let allFiles = [];

        let tgt = evt.target || window.event.srcElement,
            files = tgt.files;

        for (let x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
            // FileReader support
            if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
                let fr = new FileReader();
                fr.readAsDataURL(files[x]);
                fr.onload = function () {
                    allFiles.push(fr.result);
                }
            }
            // Not supported
            else {
                // fallback -- perhaps submit the input to an iframe and temporarily store
                // them on the server until the user's session ends.
            }
        }

        resolve(allFiles);
    });
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
    margin: 30px 60px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-style: ridge;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
    flex: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

.img-overlay {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;

}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    top: 6px;
    right: 3px;
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
}


.column img {
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .column {
        min-width: 50%;
    }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        min-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="load">
        <input type="file" name="picField" id="picField" size="24" onchange="preview_2(this);" alt="" accept="image/*"
            multiple />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column column1">
        </div>
        <div class="column column2">
        </div>
        <div class="column column3">
        </div>
        <div class="column column4">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="/app.js"></script>

</html>
```

I expected that the code would wait until loadAllFiles() returned a promise. First I thought something was wrong in my function, because allFiles was an empty array when I printed it.

But when I set a timeout of 2 seconds all the values are in the array.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like you are using `await` on `loadAllFiles`, which is not an `async` functio

Comment: This won't completely fix your problem, but for starters, you should be resolving from within the fr.onload.

Answer (score 1):

You want to wait to get the source from **getImgFromDom()**. So we use this function as a Promise, and wait for the resolved result in the `then` block. When you receive the data, we want to load the files with **loadAllFiles()**. Here we receive the files with the provided source and return the files with the `resolve` or return an error with the `reject`.

```
function loadImg(evt) {
  this.getImgFromDom().then(imgInDom => {
    this.loadAllFiles(imgInDom, evt)
      .then(allFiles => {
        // console.log(allFiles) or return the files
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // reject error here
      });
  })
```

```
function getImgFromDom(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // logic here
    resolve(source);
  });
}
```

```
function loadAllFiles(imgFromDom, evt): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // logic here
    resolve(allFiles);
    // error logic here
    reject();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem, by resolving from within the fr.onload, like zero298 suggested:

```js
function loadAllFiles(imgFromDom, evt) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {

        let allFiles = [];
        allFiles = allFiles.concat(imgFromDom);

        let tgt = evt.target || window.event.srcElement,
            files = tgt.files;

        for (let x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
            // FileReader support
            if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
                let fr = new FileReader();
                fr.readAsDataURL(files[x]);
                fr.onload = function () {
                    allFiles.push(fr.result);
                    if (x == files.length - 1) {
                        console.log(allFiles)
                        resolve(allFiles);
                    }

                }
            }
            // Not supported
            else {
                // fallback -- perhaps submit the input to an iframe and temporarily store
                // them on the server until the user's session ends.
            }
        }


    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're already using promises, I would chain them. Replace your `loadImg` method with the following:

```
function loadImg(evt) {
    getImgFromDom().then(imgInDom => {
      return loadAllFiles(imgInDom, evt)
    }).then(allFiles => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(allFiles))
    }).catch(error => {
      console.warn(error);
    });
}
```

Use this with the disclaimer that I just wrote it with out testing. :)